# Extracting a certain value and displaying it on a different page on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

[image]

I have recently been using Sharepoint Online. One of my tasks involves displaying the number of entries in a SharePoint list on the Home page of the site and, when clicked upon, must lead to the list page.

So far, I have figured out how I can add a link on the "#Number of Entries". Please refer to the image - I need help in displaying the Actual Number of Entries.

Any help would be appreciated. Image of sample web layout (for Representational Purposes only)

Comment: You can use JSOM script to get the count of list items and then display on home page using script editor web part.

Comment: @PS Thank you, however, can you please provide some more insight on your solution. Some helpful resources (links, etc.) regarding your suggested solution could help.

Comment: I do not have specific link with me, but you can google seach for "JSOM get list item count".

Comment: You might be interested in experimenting with the CQWP (Content Query Web Part) - it is a means of running a search for content in a different part of Sharepoint and showing the results.

Comment: @Tally Thank you for your suggestion. I'll check this out too!